# Why is my CSS box not changing colors?

Tags: html, css

Here I made a box with the color blue. Then a applied a green class, the box is staying blue. Why is this?

https://jsfiddle.net/70puf6jq/

```
<div class='box green'>

</div>

.box{
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;

  background-color: blue;
}

.box .green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

Why isn't the box green?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are attempting to target `.box .green`, which would be an element with a class of `.green` that is a **child** of `.box`. A successful change to `.box .green` is demonstrated in the following snippet, where a child has been added:

```css
.green {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.box .green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class='box'>
  <div class='green'></div>
</div>
```

In order to target two different classes on the same element, you need to not put a space between the two class selectors:

```css
.box {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.box.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class='box green'></div>
```

Hope this helps! :)